# Sending tweets using Android

Tags: android, twitter

I want to send a tweet from Android.I have executed the following code.But I am not bale to send any tweets.Avtually the button I created is not working.Can anybody tel me wats the prob?

This is my code..

```
import android.app.Activity;

import android.content.ActivityNotFoundException;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.os.Bundle;

public class TwidgitPublicIntent extends Activity implements OnClickListener {

    private static final int TWIDGIT_REQUEST_CODE = 2564;
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        ((Button)findViewById(R.id.tweet_button)).setOnClickListener(this);
        ((Button)findViewById(R.id.mention_button)).setOnClickListener(this);
        ((Button)findViewById(R.id.retweet_button)).setOnClickListener(this);
        ((Button)findViewById(R.id.message_button)).setOnClickListener(this);
    }
    public void onClick(View v) {
        switch(v.getId()) {
            case R.id.tweet_button:

                // Standard tweet
                Intent tIntent = new Intent("com.disretrospect.twidgit.TWEET");
                tIntent.putExtra("com.disretrospect.twidgit.extras.MESSAGE", "_message_in_here_");
                try {
                    this.startActivityForResult(tIntent, TWIDGIT_REQUEST_CODE);
                } catch (ActivityNotFoundException e) {
                    // If Twidgit is not installed
                }

                break;
            case R.id.mention_button:

                // Mention
                Intent mIntent = new Intent("com.disretrospect.twidgit.MENTION");
                mIntent.putExtra("com.disretrospect.twidgit.extras.TO", "_username_to_xmention_");
                mIntent.putExtra("com.disretrospect.twidgit.extras.MESSAGE", "_message_in_here_");
                try {
                    this.startActivityForResult(mIntent, TWIDGIT_REQUEST_CODE);
                } catch (ActivityNotFoundException e) {
                    // If Twidgit is not installed
                }

                break;
            case R.id.retweet_button:

                // Retweet a tweet
                Intent rtIntent = new Intent("com.disretrospect.twidgit.RETWEET");
                rtIntent.putExtra("com.disretrospect.twidgit.extras.MESSAGE", "_message_in_here_");
                rtIntent.putExtra("com.disretrospect.twidgit.extras.VIA", "_original_author_of_tweet_name_");
                try {
                    this.startActivityForResult(rtIntent, TWIDGIT_REQUEST_CODE);
                } catch (ActivityNotFoundException e) {
                    // If Twidgit is not installed
                }

                break;
            case R.id.message_button:

                // Send DM
                Intent dmIntent = new Intent("com.disretrospect.twidgit.DIRECT_MESSAGE");
                dmIntent.putExtra("com.disretrospect.twidgit.extras.TO", "_username_to_send_dm_to_");
                dmIntent.putExtra("com.disretrospect.twidgit.extras.MESSAGE", "_message_in_here_");
                try {
                    this.startActivityForResult(dmIntent, TWIDGIT_REQUEST_CODE);
                } catch (ActivityNotFoundException e) {
                    // If Twidgit is not installed
                }

                break;
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

        // Check result code
        if(resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
            // Check requestCode
            switch(requestCode) {
                case TWIDGIT_REQUEST_CODE:
                    // Handle successful return
                break;
            }
        } else if(resultCode == Activity.RESULT_CANCELED){
            // Handle canceled activity
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not able to edit your post so i have to put this in an answer: could you provide more details about the problem? More precisely, what do you mean by "the button is not working?" Is anything happening when you click the button, or not? If nothing happens, might be that you run into the ActivityNotFoundException. Since it is catched, but no action is taken, it's transparent. Have you tried debugging, with a break point on the onClick method?